# Если скрыть репозиторий GitHub, бесплатный хостинг GitHub Pages будет работать?

Tags: github

У меня бесплатный хостинг GitHub, через репозиторий, если скрыть репозиторий, хостинг будет работать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, нет. На бесплатном плане GitHub Pages работают [только с публичными репо](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-github-pages).

> GitHub Pages is available **in public repositories with GitHub Free**, and in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro, ...